# Change constant value and broadcast to sub controllers in angular 1.4.9

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to change the value of a constant from root controller. 
Then the state goes to a login controller where the value of constant is still the old one.

Initially the CONSTANT is set like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module("app");
myApp.constant("clientsList", [{"object1":....}]);
```

I have a logout function that contains

```
$rootScope.$emit('updateClients', null);
$state.go('login', {}, {reload: true});
```

In root controller:

```
> $rootScope.$on('updateClients', function(event, clients) {
>         _this.clientsList = clients;
>         angular.module("app").constant("clientsList", clients);
>     });
```

And in login controller, after being redirected by state.go('login'):

```
.controller('LoginController', LoginController);
function LoginController(clientsList) {
   // clientsList still have the old value here:
}
```

How can I change the value of the clientsList constant?

Comment: "Change constant" that should be enough to tell you that you shouldn't be doing that :p

Comment: I though about this. But is a provider containing data related to logged in user. I could use a service otherwise...

Comment: Ya, always use a provider (service or factory) to store data you want globally accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use a factory (or a service if you prefer) to execute the call to the API and store the result. This way you will have access to these values in all of your controllers.

I created this dummy example where we use the same factory to fetch the clients and store, and then we get the clientsList to two different controllers:

```js
angular.module('webapp', [])
      .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, DummyFactory) {
          $scope.clientsList   = [];
          $scope.getClients = function () {
            DummyFactory.getClients().then(function(clientsList) {
              $scope.clientsList = clientsList;
            });
          };
     
      })
      .controller('OtherCtrl', function($scope, DummyFactory) {
          $scope.clientsList = DummyFactory.clientsList; 
      })
      .factory('DummyFactory', function ($q, $timeout) {
        var clientsList = [];
      
        var getClients = function () {
          // Here replace with your service call
          return $q(function (resolve) {
              $timeout(function () { 
                var result = [{name: 'a'}, {name:'b'}];
                
                // Here I use this so I don't create a new array
                // this way the reference is not lost in "Other Controller"
                // You could assign a new array, but then you 
                // would have to have a $watch on the "OtherController"
                Array.prototype.push.apply(clientsList, result);
                resolve(clientsList);
              }, 500);
          });
        };
        
        return { 
          clientsList: clientsList, 
          getClients: getClients 
        };
      });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="webapp">
    <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
            <h1>App Controller:</h1>
            <button ng-click="getClients()">GET CLIENTS</button>
            <ul ng-repeat="item in clientsList">
               <li ng-bind="item.name"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      
        <div ng-controller="OtherCtrl">
          <h1>Other Controller:</h1>
          <ul ng-repeat="item in clientsList">
               <li ng-bind="item.name"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```